# $authWithPassword is not a function in AngularFire 2.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I've seen posts about this problem before, but they're either outdated or offer a solution very similar to my setup.

Basically, I have two functions in my controller: authCtrl.login and authCtrl.register. The register's call to Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword() works fine, but the login's call to Auth.$authWithPassword() does not, as I'm getting a "..is not a function" error. Can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong here.

Here's my setup:

**auth.service.js:**

```
angular.module('angularfireSlackApp')
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject){
var auth = $firebaseAuth();

return auth;
});
```

**auth.controller.js:**

```
angular.module('angularfireSlackApp')
.controller('AuthCtrl', function(Auth, $state){
var authCtrl = this;

authCtrl.user = {
  email: '',
  password: ''
};

authCtrl.login = function() {
// Why is this not a function
Auth.$authWithPassword(authCtrl.user)
.then(function (auth){
  $state.go('home');
}, function (error){
  authCtrl.error = error;
});
}

authCtrl.register = function() {
Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authCtrl.user.email, authCtrl.user.password)
.then(function (user){
  authCtrl.login();
}, function (error){
  authCtrl.error = error;
});
}

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `$signInWithEmailAndPassword`

See documentation:
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#signinwithemailandpasswordemail-password

Comment: My man!

It's interesting because this is what I found in the source code for the latest version of AngularFire in regards to the createUserWithEmailAndPassword:

"* Creates a new email/password user. Note that this function only creates the user, if you
     * wish to log in as the newly created user, call $authWithPassword() after the promise for
     * this method has been resolved."

I figured I'd just use that logic in it's own function and then call the login function from inside the register. Either way, works great now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more complete answer building on what Aaron Saunders answered using angularjs and angularfire:

```
var auth = $firebaseAuth();

$scope.loginUser = function (email, password) {
        auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(firebaseUser) {
            console.log("User Logged in successfully with uid: " + firebaseUser.uid);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("An Authentication error occurred: " + error);
        });
    };
```