# TypeError: firebase.auth() is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am setting a new firebase project. In the project I try to use firebase.auth() to create a new user with user email and password. However, when I use firebase serve and do a post request with the link in postman, i get an error which says firebase.auth is not a function.

I believe that there are questions regarding this issue, however I tried all the solutions that they have provided but none of the worked for me.

I tried:
- Adding require firebase/auth
- Deleting node modules and reinstalling firebase and firebase functions
- Import firebase and functions in different order
- Install firebase and functions in a different order
- Create a new project and install firebase and functions from scratch

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx,
    authDomain: "xx",
    databaseURL: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = require('express')();

admin.initializeApp();

//Signup route

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
        handle: req.body.handle,
    }

    // TODO: validate data

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then(data => {
        return res.status(201).json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully`})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({error: err.code});
    });
});
```

Expected results: get status 201 on postman and created new user in firebase

Actual results: TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function. In the console and postman.

Comment: Pls check out [another thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38670779/4632372). It may help.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand the difference of [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js) and [Firebase Admin SDK for Node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node).

The Firebase JavaScript SDK is for the client side.

Firebase Admin SDK is for the server side(like the Cloud Functions).

So in your case, you should use [admin.auth().createUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth?hl=ja#createUser) .

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to instantiate the application using the client sdk instead of the server.

You need to use a `private key instead`, to get one go to your firebase console -> `Project Overview` -> `Service accounts` -> `Generate new private key`

then after you download and include the key in your project:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const serviceAccount = require('your_firebase_key/path/goes/here')
admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
})
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing `firebase` as well as `firebase-tools`.  I had initially only installed `firebase-tools`.  Try running `npm i firebase`, restart the server `firebase serve` and see if you're still having the issue.